# Grafana OPCUA Plugin failed to start

Tags: grafana, opc-ua, portainer

I'm new to both portainer and grafana and I'm attempting to get an OPC UA connection up and running.

Grafana is running on a container on portainer. I have access to the front end/console etc.

When running "grafana-server restart" there are a few errors, some about port 3000 "address already in use". But what's important here, the opcua plugin fails to start with error:

`Unrecognized remote plugin message: \n\nThis usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply\nneeds to be recompiled to support the latest protocol.`

I've installed using the basic "grafana-cli plugins install grafana-opcua-datasource" command. the OPCUA plugin is an option on the front end, however, testing it simply gives me a "plugin unavailable" popup. I have upgraded Grafana and updated the plugin. The Grafana version is high enough to work with the plugin (according to https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-opcua-datasource/?tab=installation)

Anyone have any ideas of where I can at least look for problems?

Full error log from server restart:

```
EROR[02-08|13:24:31] Failed to start plugin                   logger=plugins.backend pluginId=grafana-opcua-datasource error="Unrecognized remote plugin message: \n\nThis usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply\nneeds to be recompiled to support the latest protocol."
WARN[02-08|13:24:31] plugin failed to exit gracefully         logger=plugins.backend pluginId=grafana-opcua-datasource
EROR[02-08|13:24:32] A service failed                         logger=server err="failed to open listener on address 0.0.0.0:3000: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: bind: address already in use"
EROR[02-08|13:24:32] Server shutdown                          logger=server reason="failed to open listener on address 0.0.0.0:3000: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: bind: address already in use"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same or similar problem:

```
NFO[04-21|07:01:05] Plugin registered                        logger=plugin.manager pluginId=alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app
INFO[04-21|07:01:05] Plugin registered                        logger=plugin.manager pluginId=grafana-clock-panel
INFO[04-21|07:01:05] Plugin registered                        logger=plugin.manager pluginId=grafana-opcua-datasource
EROR[04-21|07:01:05] Could not start plugin                   logger=plugin.manager pluginId=grafana-opcua-datasource err="Unrecognized remote plugin message: \n\nThis usually means that the plugin is either invalid or simply\nneeds to be recompiled to support the latest protocol."
INFO[04-21|07:01:05] Plugin registered                        logger=plugin.manager pluginId=grafana-piechart-panel
INFO[04-21|07:01:05] Plugin registered                        logger=plugin.manager pluginId=grafana-simple-json-datasource
INFO[04-21|07:01:05] Plugin registered                        logger=plugin.manager pluginId=alexanderzobnin-zabbix-datasource
INFO[04-21|07:01:05] Profiler                                 logger=plugin.alexanderzobnin-zabbix-datasource enabled=false
WARN[04-21|07:01:05] Plugin process is running with elevated privileges. This is not recommended logger=plugin.alexanderzobnin-zabbix-datasource
INFO[04-21|07:01:05] Query Service initialization             logger=query_data
```

It's a .net aplication right?
i tried it in a dockerized enviroment on a debian host.
logger=settings version=8.4.7 commit=23bf3ef043 branch=HEAD compiled=2022-04-19T16:05:49+0000

i also tried to add the .net enviroment:

```
FROM grafana/grafana:latest

USER root

RUN apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib wget
RUN apk add libgdiplus --repository https://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet 

RUN wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh
RUN chmod +x dotnet-install.sh
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c 3.1 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c 5.0 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet
RUN ./dotnet-install.sh -c 6.0 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet

RUN grafana-cli plugins install grafana-opcua-datasource
```

but with the same result.